# Time dependence of de Broglie wavelength of an electron with initial velocity $V\hat{\imath}$ and in a uniform magnetic field $B\hat{\jmath}$

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, kinematics, momentum, charge

I am supposed to comment on the time dependence of de Broglie wavelength of an electron with initial velocity $V\hat{\imath}$ and in a uniform magnetic field $B\hat{\jmath}$.

Obviously since the electron is a negatively charged particle force on it will be in $-\hat{k}$-direction.

And the velocity in $z$-direction can be written as, $\vec{V}_z=\frac{1}{2}\frac{eVB}{m}t^{2}(-\hat{k})$

There will be no  velocity in $y$-direction as there is no acceleration and the velocity in $x$-direction will remain constant at $V\hat{\imath}$

So quite clearly the velocity in $-z$-direction will increase as time increases and that will increase the momentum and since $\lambda\propto\frac{1}{\mathrm{momentum}}$, the de Broglie wavelength would decrease with time. But the book says that the de Broglie wavelength would remain constant with time. The reason it provides is: "Force is perpendicular to both $\vec{V}$
and $\vec{B}$ and the magnitude of $\vec{V}$ will not change. It means momentum will not change."

Answer (score 3):

$|\mathbf{v}|$ does not change, as $\frac{d}{dt} \mathbf{v}^2=2 \, \mathbf{v} \cdot\dot{\mathbf{v}}=\frac{2q}{m} \mathbf{v} \cdot (\mathbf{v} \times \mathbf{B})=0 $.